# Rails best practice - handling errors rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I am new to rails. I want to know the best way to handle inputs errors in rails. Using `:message` in `validates_format_of method` then checking in the views the value of the hash or initializing the model with a `ActiveModel::Errors.new`, and then using it in the views (passing in the model `attr_reader :errors`), or other any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `:message` in`validates_format_of method` then checking in the views, This is a universal practice
The guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#error_messages-and-error_messages_for

Answer (score 0):

A good way to validate input errors is to have both client-side and server-side validations. You can rely on Rails validators on your models, and on the front end you can either use the newer HTML elements, javascript, or a combination of both.

With regards to Rails validations specifically, I don't think you need to stray too far from the conventions. Obviously if you need a different strategy you can definitely incorporate it, but at that point I would definitely suggest adding tests (which is not something I typically do for Rails validations).